# Pandas Object to String

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have this data frame...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':['A','A','B','B']})
```

I want to extract the first 'A' from COL1 as a string value so it looks like this: 'A' 
in Python because when I use it in a chart title via MatPlotLib, it displays as '0 A dtype:object' instead of just 'A.'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) or [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) methods of dataframe from column:

```
In [140]: df.COL1.iloc[0]
Out[140]: 'A'

In [141]: df.COL1.ix[0]
Out[141]: 'A'
```

If you need to extract from dataframe you could do `iloc[0][0]`:

```
In [145]: df.iloc[0]
Out[145]: 
COL1    A
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [146]: df.iloc[0][0]
Out[146]: 'A'
```

You could also use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) method which is faster:

```
In [151]: df.COL1.iat[0]
Out[151]: 'A'
```